# Is there a easy way to move a field on a remote graphql schema?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js, graphql-tools

I am trying to integrate with a remote schema using graphql-tools for node.

I have the remote schema but unfortunately all of the queries are defined on the `Viewer` type rather than the `Query` type.

I would like to use `graphql-tools` to transform the schema and move some of the fields from the `Viewer` type to the `Query` type.

I have tried a couple of different methods: including `delegateToSchema` in a custom resolver and `ExtractField` transformations, but they haven't worked. `delegateToSchema` seems like the correct way to do it but unfortunately it can only delegate to a root type not a type like `Viewer`.

Does anyone know how I could add a field to the `Query` type that delegates to a field on the `Viewer` type?